# Drools Memory Leak

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, heap-memory, drools

Recently our Microservice which 'lives' on a pod on Kubernetes failed with heap out of memory related issues. No problem till then, we gave some more resources and everything works as expected. Given this incident we started taking some heap dumps to analyze them and check what the root cause could be.

MAT Tool analysis spots 3 Leak Suspects as can be seen below:
[MAT Heap Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcUFq.png)

We also used JXRay tool to have an analysis and thats the results:
[JXRay Heap Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mevjD.png)

Everything was drools related thats why we used VisualVM to check the object memory usage:
[VisualVM Objects Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptdcT.png)

Under MVELCompilationUnit there are almost 50.000 object references org.drools.core.base.mvel.MVELCompilationUnit#1 , org.drools.core.base.mvel.MVELCompilationUnit#2......50.000

Does this makes sense?

At this point its worth mentioning that our project atm uses almost 1000 rules which are loaded through an external kjar.
Analyzing with VisualVM by executing an operation that fires all rules and performing a manual GC afterwards does not show any issues since the heap memory is cleaned afterwards.

Additionally regarding our code atm:

We use statefull drool sessions, per user a KiesSession is created, it fires all the rules twice and it gets disposed at the end of its journey.

So.. Do you think this is actually a memory leak?
How could we investigate it further?
Should we use a different approach of instantiating/firing rules? Maybe a session pool could help?

Thank in advance.

[UPDATE 1#]
Monitoring Heap Memory before running this TestController endpoint
indicates like 118000.... bytes uses

After testing it goes up to 250000... like 2x ..
Performing a GC afterwards does not free up the used heap memory.
Rerunning the test does not make the heap memory increase further though. Its like the KieContainer is being loaded with rules on its first call and then it stays on memory. Is this expected?

```
public void fireRules() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(getUsedMemory());
        KieSession testSession = ruleEngine.getNewSession("XXX");
        testSession.fireAllRules();
        testSession.dispose();
    }
}

private Long getUsedMemory() {
    System.gc();
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    return runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
}
```

The injected RuleEngine looks like:

```
public RuleEngine(String groupId, String artifactId, String versionId, String sessionName) {
    this.releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl(groupId, artifactId, versionId);
    this.sessionName = sessionName;
    this.kieContainer = getKieContainer();
    this.globalObjects.put("helper", new CatalogueGlobalHelper());
}
```

Comment: What does the `RuleEngine.getKieContainer()` method do? From the threaddump it looks like the leak might be there

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without a reproducer... any chance you can share the spring-boot based application (not necessarily the KJAR) with a github repo link and share it on the [drools-usage](https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage) or [kogito-development](https://groups.google.com/g/kogito-development) mailing list?

Just based on the information provided, it *seems* to me you are actually *loading* the KJAR per request, which is already arguable, and further in your application code you might be inadvertently not releasing the *compilation* side of the loaded KJAR.

> Do you think this is actually a memory leak?

So far, I would doubt is a memory leak in the Drools API, seems suspicious of a non-released resources in your "loading" code.

> How could we investigate it further?

Sharing a reproducer of your application (not necessarily the KJAR). Even better, you can check if the same undesired behaviour happens with a KJAR not containing your business logic, but just some example rules.

> Should we use a different approach of instantiating/firing rules?

So far, I would be led to believe the problem is indeed there, the way you instantiate the KieContainwer.

> Maybe a session pool could help?

If my suspect is proved correct, a session pool would not help.

To me, the best in a cloud-native environment, is just to migrate to Kogito.

If you really need your application in the way you have it designed, I would double check the part which is in charge of locating, loading and instantiating the KJAR into a KieContainer.
Providing that with a reproducer, or sharing at least the minimal code which allow investigation on mailing-lists, is probably more pragmatic.

Comment: Thank you! Check update on my initial post please!

Comment: sorry but you are ignoring "Providing that with a reproducer," because again there is zero insights how the kiecontainer is created (getKieContainer()) so going back/forth like this is not efficient. Imho, provide reproducer, share it via mailing-list as I originally mentioned. my2c.